# VB.NET WebBrowser Control OnClick Event Not Triggering

Tags: vb.net, onclick, click, webbrowser-control, invokemember

I'm using Vb.Net to trigger event listeners in a web-browser control, however it only seems to work on some site and not on others...

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("button name").InvokeMember("click")
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("button name").InvokeMember("Onclick")
```

It works on sites like adf.ly, gmail, google, but not on others.
for example, On the airserver log in website (http://www.airserver.com/Download) it only works for some buttons. The "download for free" and "buy now" buttons all work.

But, the popup (comes up when you press download for free) has a "register for trial" button. I have tried to use these codes, they do not work. (Yes, I have put in my name and email into the required fields)

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("registrButton").InvokeMember("click")
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("registrButton").InvokeMember("Onclick")
```

I have also looked at the chrome event break-point, it tells me that it a "click" event was triggered.

This is the html code for the button if you are not bothered to go to airserver

```
<a id="registrButton" class="button register" href="#" onclick="$('#promoRequest').submit();return false;">Register for Trial</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because it's a pop up (probably ajax and the code is not viewable in the webbrowser).

But the solution is here, use this link would 100% work:
http://www.airserver.com/register/PC

then redirect back to your download page, and do whatever you were doing.